# Flutter Http post request is throwing Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, http, exception, post

I made a post request for user sign up. I have followed this link- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data

But I am getting the following exception- Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Here is the method-

```
Future<User> createUser(
  String fullName, String email, String userName, String password) async {
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.https('http://example.com/signup.php', 'user'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    'fullname': fullName,
    'email': email,
    'username': userName,
    'password': password
  }),
);

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  s = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(s);
  return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to create user.');
}
```

}

Comment: the error occurs when your api syntax is wrong e.g sometime it solved by changing http to https

Comment: what you going to do with this line ?  `Uri.https('http://example.com/signup.php', 'user'),` I think this is good enough `await http.post(http://example.com/signup.php, body: {... });`

Comment: @JohnJoe After implementing your suggestion the exception is gone. Now it is throwing failed to create user.

Comment: make sure all the params contains value, and the url is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify my method for making it working.

This is the code-

```
Future<User> createUser(
  String fullName, String email, String userName, String password) async {
final response = await http.post('https://andoirdtvapp.hiphopnblog.com/signup.php',
  
  body: {
    'fullname' : fullName,
    'email' : email,
    'username' : userName,
    'password' : password,
  },
);
  s = response.body;
  return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
```